# Why i am not able to create child folders within parent folder structure in hadoop hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am facing issues while creating child folders (recursive) within parent folder structure in HDFS

Using Hadoop ver 2.7.1

sample :   hadoop fs -mkdir /test/sample/logfiles

If i type in the above command in terminal, i am not able to create the complete folder structure up until level2 (logFiles).

i am able to create test/sample if using below 
hadoop fs -mkdir /test/sample

Any internal configuration should be done which is limiting the folder creation structure level.?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks - Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-p` flag:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /test/sample/logfiles
```

Answer (score 2):

From hadoop commands [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#mkdir):

> **Usage**: hadoop fs -mkdir [-p]
>
> Takes path uri’s as argument and creates directories.
>
> **Options**:
>
> The -p option behavior is much like Unix mkdir -p, creating parent
>   directories along the path.

Comment: Thank you @daemon12 for documentation link !